# ReactでWarning: The tag <image> is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.が未解決

Tags: reactjs, react-jsx

以下のワーニングが解決できずに困っています。
解決のためのアドバイスを頂けましたら幸いです。

```
react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: The tag <image> is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.
    at image
    at ProfilePicture
    at App
```

##### 開発環境

・Reactのバージョン：React18
・OS：Windows10
・エディタ：VSCode
・ブラウザ：Chrome（バージョン: 100.0.4896.127）

#### 試したこと

- imageタグを持つコンポーネント（ProfilePicture.jsx）のファイル名、関数を格納する変数(export const ProfilePicture)、import先のコンポーネント名の先頭文字が大文字になっているかの確認
- imageタグがReactでは使えないのか？あるいは何か特殊な使い方があるのか？あるいはReact専用のimageタグのようなものがあるのか？をネットで調査

#### ソースコード

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { App } from "./App";

const container = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(container); // createRoot(container!) if you use TypeScript
root.render(<App tab="home" />);
```

App.jsx

```
import { Fragment } from "react";
import { ProfilePicture } from "./components/ProfilePicture";

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <ProfilePicture></ProfilePicture>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

ProfilePicture.jsx

```
import Icon from "../images/MyProfilePic.jpg";

export const ProfilePicture = () => {
  return <image src={Icon} alt="アイコン"></image>;
};
```

ファイル構成

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決しました。
イメージタグのタグ名が間違ってました。
誤：image
正：img

英語のスペルで正しいものがタグ名だと思い込んでいたので、
今後はタグ名が期待する動作をするタグ名かどうか調べて確認します。